For which cardinals $\kappa$ is the theory of a single bijection lacking cycles $\kappa$-categorical?
I'm currently stuck on Exercise 2.5.13 of David Marker's model theory text. The full statement of the exercise is as follows:
Let $\mathscr{L}$ be the language containing a single unary function symbol $s$, and let $T$ be the $\mathscr{L}$-theory asserting that $s$ is a bijection with no cycles (i.e., for each $x$, $s^n(x) \neq x$ for any $n$). For what cardinals $\kappa$ is $T$ $\kappa$-categorical?
Since $T$ evidently does not have any finite models, I had a hunch that the key to this problem was showing that $T$ is not complete (if this were to be true, then Vaught's test would imply that $T$ was not $\kappa$-categorical for any $\kappa$). I tried to do this by writing a sentence $\phi$ differentiating the $\mathscr{L}$-structures $(\mathbf{Z}, s_1)$ and $(\mathbf{Z}, s_2)$ where $s_k$ is given by $x \mapsto x + k$: in particular, I wanted to express the fact that in the former structure the "action" by $s_1$ is transitive, i.e. for any two distinct elements $x, y \in \mathbf{Z}$ it is either the case that there exists $m$ such that $s^m(x) = y$, or that there exists $n$ such that $s^n(y) = x$.  I have come to conclude, however, that this property cannot be expressed in a (finite) $\mathscr{L}$-sentence, and so I am no longer confident that this approach will actually yield fruit.
Now, in investigating the set of $\mathscr{L}$-structures given by $\{(\mathbf{Z}, s_n): n \in \omega\}$, I have come to think that they are all nonisomorphic, but I haven't been able to prove this. I also have a hunch that this set fully represents countable models of $T$ up to isomorphism, but I am not sure how to prove that either; I do recall from set theory that for an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ the number of permutations of a $\kappa$ cardinality set is $2^\kappa$, but I am again not sure how I can use this to determine the cardinality of the set of permutations lacking cycles, although I have another hunch that this is $\kappa$.
I am not really looking for a full solution, but I would sincerely appreciate an evaluation of my approach and maybe a pointer or two. Thanks!

The key is to look at the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if there is an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $y=s^n(x)$ or $x = s^n(y).$ The theory is complete, but you are correct that $(\mathbb Z,s_n)$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ are countably many non-isomorphic countable models.

Actually you missed exactly one countable model: it's also possible for there to be countably many $\mathbb{Z}$-chains, for example $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$ with $s(z, n) = (z+1, n)$.

The models of $T$ are exactly the "unions of $\mathbb{Z}$-chains" - writing "$\sim^\mathcal{M}$" for the smallest equivalence relation containing $s$ in a given model $\mathcal{M}$, if $\mathcal{M}\models T$ then $\mathcal{M}$ is a disjoint union of $\sim^\mathcal{M}$-classes and each $\sim^\mathcal{M}$-class is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z};\mathit{succ})$. This means that each model $\mathcal{M}$ of $T$ is fully described, up to isomorphism, by a single cardinal $\mu_\mathcal{M}$, namely $\mu_\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}/\sim^\mathcal{M}$.
Now what does $\mu_\mathcal{M}$ tell you about $\vert\mathcal{M}\vert$? In particular, when is $$\vert\mathcal{M}\vert=\vert\mathcal{N}\vert\quad\implies\quad\mu_\mathcal{M}=\mu_\mathcal{N}$$ true?

 If $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are uncountable models of $T$, then $\vert\mathcal{M}\vert=\vert\mathcal{N}\vert$ iff $\mu_\mathcal{M}=\mu_\mathcal{N}$. So $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical whenever $\kappa$ is uncountable. Conversely, we can show directly that $T$ isn't $\omega$-categorical.


Ah I see, so we literally just define the "finitary orbits", each one of which is immediately seen to be isomorphic to $(\mathbf{Z}, s)$. I was needlessly complicating the situation — thank you.
